# Como fazer uma variável aparecer na função write em prolog

Tags: prolog

Eu estou fazendo um programa que apresenta vários cães, e eu quero fazer de um jeito que seja mais rápido para escrever as características dos cães. Por exemplo, o código seguinte

```
raca(pitbull).
raca(shiba).
raca(boxer).
raca(poodle).
raca(bullte_terrier).
sexo(macho).
sexo(femea).

cor(castanho).
cor(preto).
cor(branco).
cor(tricolor).
cor(pintado).
cor(malhado).

pelo(longo).
pelo(curto).

peso(15kg).




print(X):-
    write(X).

cao(trovao):-
    sexo(macho),
    raca(pitbull),
    cor(marrom),
    pelo(curto),
    write('raca: '),nl,
    write('nascimento: 1999'),nl,
    write('cor: marrom'),nl
    write('pelo: curto').
```

O que eu quero é um jeito de no write eu conseguir printar a variável que está guardando a ifnromação. Exemplo

```
X = cor(marrom),

write(cor: X).
```

e aí seria impresso no terminal "cor: marrom", mas não está dando certo, não sei como colocar a variável no write. Podem me ajudar?

Comment: O prolog é uma linguagem funcional, diferente da linguagem imperativa como a maioria das linguagens (C, Java, Javascript, ...). Nesse tipo de linguagem não existem variáveis explicitas.

Comment: O que você quer retornar da função *cor(marrom)* ? Essa função não tem retorno, assim como qualquer função do prolog. Ele só retonar verdadeiro ou falso

Comment: = não significa atribuição, e sim igualdade (em alguns compiladores)

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

Talvez um programa mais simples te ajude a entender o que se deve fazer. O programa abaixo escreve o nome do pai de uma pessoa:

```
homem(joao).
homem(jose).

mulher(maria).

pai(joao, jose).
pai(joao, maria).

imprime_pai(X):- homem(Y), pai(Y,X), write('o pai de '), write(X), write(' é '), write(Y),!.
```

Basta salvar num arquivo e carregar (com consult) no Prolog. Depois você pode testar com:

```
?- imprime_pai(maria).
o pai de maria é joao
true.
```

Ou:

```
?- imprime_pai(jose).
o pai de jose é joao
true.
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a função format, que tem uma sintaxe parecida com o printf do C, exceto que onde C/Java usam '%', Prolog usa '~':

```erlang
% Note que podemos usar outros caracteres além de ASCII ;)
cão(nome(trovão), raça(pitbull), nascimento(1999), cor(marrom), pelo(curto)).

print_cão(Nome) :-
  % Busca o cão na base de conhecimento.
  cão(nome(Nome), raça(Raça), nascimento(Ano), cor(Cor), pelo(Pelo)),
  % Valida que os dados correspondem às constantes definidas.
  raça(Raça),
  nascimento(Ano),
  cor(Cor),
  pelo(Pelo),
  % Imprime as informações do cão
  format("nome: ~w~nraça: ~w~nnascimento: ~w~ncor: ~w~npelo: ~w~n", [Nome, Raça, Ano, Cor, Pelo]).
```